# Combining 2 excel sheets in python

Tags: python, excel

I have 2 csv sheets:

I am trying to find a way to merge table2 onto table1. Whenever table1 and table2 have the same Name value then replace the corresponding Price in table1 with the one found in table2 otherwise leave table1 as is.

Current code:

```
table1 = pd.read_csv('path/table1.csv')
table2 = pd.read_csv('path/table2.csv')
print(table1)
print(table2)

new_table= pd.merge(table1, table2, left_on='Name ',right_on='Name ', how='left')
print(new_table)
```

However, this doesn't overwrite table1, it leads to the following error:

```
Unnamed: 0  Price  Name   ATT1  ATT2
0           0     12   APPL    69    81
1           1    900  GOOGL   303   392
2           2     32    INV    39     9
   Unnamed: 0  Price     Name 
0           0   1231      APPL
1           1     39  FACEBOOK

 Unnamed: 0_x  Price_x  Name   ATT1  ATT2  Unnamed: 0_y  Price_y
0             0       12   APPL    69    81           0.0   1231.0
1             1      900  GOOGL   303   392           NaN      NaN
2             2       32    INV    39     9           NaN      NaN
```

What i want it to return is:

```
Unnamed: 0  Price  Name   ATT1  ATT2
0           0     1231   APPL    69    81
1           1    900  GOOGL   303   392
2           2     32    INV    39     9
```

Comment: maybe you can work with `.csv` files? they are more Python-friendly (by using `pandas.read_csv` and `dataframe.to_csv` functions)

Comment: A good starting point would be to look into the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) library

Answer (score 1):

Let me lend you a hand with this. First of all, yes, you **should try to work always with `.csv`** rather than `excel` files because they are **faster** in W/R operations and probably easier to use due to they are **simpler** than `excel`.

But that should not be a problem, you just simply read the `excel` the first time (take a look at [read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)) and inmediately **save the `DataFrame` as `.csv`**. The next time you load them you do it from the new files and we are ready to go! Something like this:

```
# First time:
df = pd.read_excel(path_to_excel)
df.to_csv(path_to_csv, index=False)

# Next time just:
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)
```

To achieve what you want you could use a [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge) operation from `pandas`. If you don't know what a merge (or join) is I can hint you that it **puts together** the values from rows of both tables that belongs to the **same key**.

There are several ways of perform this task but for this case is important to keep in mind that we want to update the rows of the first table with the new values so in the end we want to **keep all the values of the first table**, for that reason the type of `merge` that we want is known as **`left` merge** (we keep all the rows of the left table, independently if exists a corresponding value on the right table). And we have to specify the value that we are going to use as **key** to unify the both tables: `Name`.

Like we have columns that are **named the same** in both tables (besides the key) I'm adding **suffixes** to make it easier to understand the fields.

```
merge = table1.merge(table2, how='left', on='Name', suffixes=['', '_2'])
```

And the result table will have these columns:

```
| Price | Name | ATT1 | ATT2 | Price_2 |
```

Now that we have merged both tables we get the values that we want to update, those are the **values of `Price`** from the **second** table that have a **corresponding** value on the **first** table:

```
update_mask = merge['Price_2'].notnull()
```

And in the last step we **update** those values from the first table:

```
table1.loc[update_mask, 'Price'] = merge.loc[update_mask, 'Price_2']
```

Hopes this clarify your ideas a bit and help you to succeed in what you are doing!

=======================  UPDATE  =======================

First, we need to explain things a little more:

The thing of converting your files from `xlsx` to `csv` is just a performance issue, you are not obligated to do it but if you do it you have to do it **just once**. So, the code for that should be something like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path_to_xlsx)
df.to_csv(path_to_save_csv, index=False)
```

Pay attention that `to_csv()` does not return the new `DataFrame`, the `DataFrame` structure is the same for both formats `xlsx` and `csv`, the function just saves the data on another format in the location you indicated.

So now you have yours `DataFrames` loaded, it doesn't matter if you did it with `read_excel()` or with `read_csv()`. Let's start from this point.

Now you can do this:

```
merge = table1.merge(table2, how='left', on='Name', suffixes=['', '_2'])
update_mask = merge['Price_2'].notnull()
table1.loc[update_mask, 'Price'] = merge.loc[update_mask, 'Price_2']
```

So if we combine everything in your code we got:

```
import pandas as pd

# JUST EXECUTE ONE PAIR FROM BELOW
# IF YOUR FILES ARE IN XLSX:
table1 = pd.read_excel('path/table1.xlsx')
table2 = pd.read_excel('path/table2.xlsx')

# IF YOUR FILES ARE IN CSV:
table1 = pd.read_csv('path/table1.csv')
table2 = pd.read_csv('path/table2.csv')


merge = table1.merge(table2, how='left', on='Name', suffixes=['', '_2'])
update_mask = merge['Price_2'].notnull()
table1.loc[update_mask, 'Price'] = merge.loc[update_mask, 'Price_2']
```

And as a final note, take care with your code because you copied `excel_1` on lines 3 and 5, but it should be `excel_2` on line 5.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I have updated the question since it isn't quite working. If you could help that would be great.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, I'll edit my answer with new info for your updated question!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, unfortunately I am still having problems. I have updated the question with images and the current code. If you could have a look that would be great. Thanks